# What is the correct way to upload a file with Haskell's curl package using the SFTP protocol?

Tags: haskell, libcurl

I've tried a variety of things to upload a file via SFTP using the curl package from Hackage, so far all of them produce the following error:

```
* About to connect() to [redacted] port 22 (#0)
*   Trying [redacted]... * connected
* Connected to [redacted] ([redacted]) port 22 (#0)
* Failure establishing ssh session
* Closing connection #0
* Failed initialization
ERROR: CurlFailedInit
```

I'm setting the following options in Haskell:

```
[…]
Curl.setopt curlLib (Curl.CurlFailOnError True)
Curl.setDefaultSSLOpts curlLib url  -- not necessary for sftp:// protocol, but shouldn't be a problem
Curl.setopt curlLib (Curl.CurlURL url)
Curl.setopt curlLib (Curl.CurlSSLVerifyHost 0)
Curl.setopt curlLib (Curl.CurlSSLVerifyPeer False)
Curl.setopt curlLib (Curl.CurlSSHAuthTypes [Curl.SSHAuthAny])
Curl.setopt curlLib (Curl.CurlUserPwd "user:password")
Curl.setopt curlLib (Curl.CurlUpload True)
[…]
```

I have verified that the URL, username, and password are correct. Additionally, I've also tried using the `SSHAuthPassword` auth type option, and setting the username and password with `CurlUserName` and `CurlUserPassword`.

Executing curl from the command line

```
$ curl -vvv --upload-file test.txt --user 'user:password' "sftp://[redacted]/~/test.txt"
```

Succeeds

```
* About to connect() to [redacted] port 22 (#0)
*   Trying [redacted]... connected
* Connected to [redacted] ([redacted]) port 22 (#0)
* Failed to read known hosts from [redacted]
* SSH host check: 0, key: [redacted]        
* SSH authentication methods available: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
* Using ssh public key file [redacted]
* Using ssh private key file [redacted]
* SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file
* Initialized password authentication
* Authentication complete
[…]
* Closing connection #0
```

The versions of the OS and libraries are as follows:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-131.12.1.el6.x86_64
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.1 (Santiago)
$ cabal info curl
[…]
Latest version installed: 1.3.8
[…]
$ curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.3.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

I don't control and have no influence over the server I'm connecting to, so switching to ssh-agent is not an option.